# programmatically set margin/ padding of textview in a listview

Tags: android, padding, margin

This is a part of main_alllatestnews.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/layout_menu"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_title"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is full of main_alllatestnewslist.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_temp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:background="@drawable/background_news_list" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_alllatestnewstitle"
    android:layout_width="134px"
    android:layout_height="80px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_particularlatestnewstitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25px" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25px" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_newsdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="15px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_newscategorytitle"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="15px" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is a part of main_alllatestnews.java

```
LayoutInflater liInflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    linear.addView(liInflater
            .inflate(R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, null));
lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
for (int i = 0; i < webservice.news.size(); i++) {
    maintitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_particularlatestnewstitle);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)maintitle.getLayoutParams(); 
    layoutParams.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0);       <-- method one

    maintitle.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);          <-- method two
    maintitle.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    int margin = 100;                           <-- method three
    ((MarginLayoutParams) maintitle.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = margin;
}
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps,
            R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, from, to);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As you can see i had used **THREE** methods to set margin/ padding of textview in a listview but not success.

I am using xml textview instead of create new.

I want to manually set because i got **if / else** statement there as did not post out.

I am totally out of idea how to set it in java.

Please provide me a idea that workable one, thanks

```
((MarginLayoutParams) maintitle.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = margin;
```

Comment: you ca do this in adapter's getView where you inflate the layout'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`maintitle.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);` (method 2) should work.

I think the problem is that, although you do a lot of changes to the `TextView`, at the end you kind of inflate a new layout again in:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, 
            R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, from, to);
```

so, make a custom adapter, then inflate and customize your `TextView` in the `getView()`.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful, (int) pixels != dp

```
public int dp2px(int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? That question was answered already in the best way, it could be and this is just like you are trying to put in something that is totally irrelevant and unclear, which doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code, it works for me.

> textView.setX(40);

My solution is for SDK 14 and above. Not in ListView but RecyclerView.